# Testing a lambda

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, lambda, rspec

I am creating an import feature that imports CSV files into several tables. I made a module called `CsvParser` which parses a CSV file and creates records. My models that receive the create actions extends the`CsvParser`. They make a call to `CsvParser.create` and pass the correct attribute order and an optional lambda called `value_parser`. This lambda transforms values in a hash to a preffered format.

```
class Mutation < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend CsvParser

  def self.import_csv(csv_file)
    attribute_order = %w[reg_nr receipt_date reference_number book_date is_credit sum balance description]

    value_parser = lambda do |h|
      h["is_credit"] = ((h["is_credit"] == 'B') if h["is_credit"].present?)
      h["sum"] = -1 * h["sum"].to_f unless h["is_credit"]
      return [h]
    end

    CsvParser.create(csv_file, self, attribute_order, value_parser)    
  end
end
```

The reason that I'm using a lambda instead of checks inside the `CsvParser.create` method is because the lambda is like a business rule that belongs to this model.

My question is how i should test this lambda. Should i test it in the model or the CsvParser? Should i test the lambda itself or the result of an array of the `self.import` method? Maybe i should make another code structure?

My CsvParser looks as follows:

```
require "csv"

module CsvParser

  def self.create(csv_file, klass, attribute_order, value_parser = nil)
    parsed_csv = CSV.parse(csv_file, col_sep: "|")

    records = []    

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      parsed_csv.each do |row|
        record = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}      
        row.each_with_index do |value, index|
          record[attribute_order[index]] = value
        end 
        if value_parser.blank?
          records << klass.create(record)
        else
          value_parser.call(record).each do |parsed_record|
            records << klass.create(parsed_record)
          end
        end
      end 
    end
    return records
  end

end
```

I'm testing the module itself:
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe CsvParser do

  it "should create relations" do
    file = File.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files/importrelaties.txt'))
    Relation.should_receive(:create).at_least(:once)
    Relation.import_csv(file).should be_kind_of Array 
  end

  it "should create mutations" do
    file = File.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files/importmutaties.txt'))
    Mutation.should_receive(:create).at_least(:once)    
    Mutation.import_csv(file).should be_kind_of Array
  end

  it "should create strategies" do
    file = File.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files/importplan.txt'))
    Strategy.should_receive(:create).at_least(:once)
    Strategy.import_csv(file).should be_kind_of Array
  end

  it "should create reservations" do
    file = File.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files/importreservering.txt'))
    Reservation.should_receive(:create).at_least(:once)
    Reservation.import_csv(file).should be_kind_of Array
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some interesting questions. A couple of notes:

1. You probably shouldn't have a return within the lambda. Just make the last statement [h].
2. If I understand the code correctly, the first and second lines of your lambda are overcomplicated. Reduce them to make them more readable and easier to refactor:

   ```
   h["is_credit"] = (h['is_credit'] == 'B') # I *think* that will do the same
   h['sum'] = h['sum'].to_f   # Your original code would have left this a string
   h['sum'] *= -1 unless h['is_credit']
   ```
3. It looks like your lambda doesn't depend on anything external (aside from `h`), so I would test it separately. You could even make it a constant:

   ```
   class Mutation < ActiveRecord::Base
     extend CsvParser    # <== See point 5 below

     PARSE_CREDIT_AND_SUM = lambda do |h|
       h["is_credit"] = (h['is_credit'] == 'B') 
       h['sum'] = h['sum'].to_f
       h['sum'] *= -1 unless h['is_credit']
       [h]
     end
   ```
4. Without knowing the rationale, it's hard to say where you should put this code. My gut instinct is that it is not the job of the CSV parser (although a good parser may detect floating point numbers and convert them from strings?) Keep your CSV parser reusable. (Note: Re-reading, I think you've answered this question yourself - it is business logic, tied to the model. Go with your gut!)
5. Lastly, you are defining and the method `CsvParser.create`. You don't need to extend CsvParser to get access to it, although if you have other facilities in CsvParser, consider making `CsvParser.create` a normal module method called something like create_from_csv_file

Comment: Thanks for your thorough, clear answer. I followed your advice and was able to test the constant because i could call Class::<constant name>. I only wonder how i should test something like this when it would be a variable in a method.

Comment: If the lambda could not be refactored out, I would test it as any other method. If it is a very complicated lambda, relying on lots of local variables, then this may indicate that it wants to be its own instance. As a general rule, methods that are hard to test need a refactor!

Comment: Today i realized there is a something called a method object. It can be used the same way as a lambda with the only difference that I can use the code of a method instead of a lambda. I think it's more cleaner than defining a lambda as a constant. So instead of passing the lambda as a parameter i now use method(:<method name>)

Comment: This is a great answer - though I'm not sure I agree with point 1. Returning from a lambda is nice and explicit. Are you thinking of return from a proc, which is a different beast?

Comment: @AlexDean There are some things in Ruby that I would rather do without. Returns within blocks/procs/lambdas can be confusing to people reading the code, especially to newcomers to the language. I always prefer a consistent rule. Entirely personal preference of course...